# Open a url on Mobile Safari on iPad 2019 iOS v12.2

Tags: ios, appium-ios, xcuitest

So I'm using XCUIApplication to open a url on Safari browser via WebDriverAgent by using the `-u` option.

```
#define SAFARI_APP @"com.apple.mobilesafari"

XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:SAFARI_APP];
[app setLaunchArguments:@[@"-u", url]];
[app launch];
```

But this is breaking on the new iPads with iOS v12.2 with the following error.

```
The -u command line option has been removed (rdar://42146540), please file a radar with your use case if you rely on this
```

Upon further debugging I found https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/pull/918/files which talks about the `-u` option. But didn't find any solutions.